# Foreach loop with counter

Tags: erlang

I would like to add a counter in this loop in order to know the row of each element of the list. Do you have a simple solution?

`lists:foreach(fun(X) .... end,Y),`

Comment: It's a bit better to state your goal rather than what you think will help you obtain your goal.  There are different answers depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Y = ["abc","def","ghi"], lists:foreach(fun(X) io:write("string ~w: ~s,[N,X]) end,Y),

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use lists:foldl or write your own function:

```
lists:foldl(fun(E,Cnt) -> ..., Cnt+1 end, 0, Y),
```

Comment: Yes ! very good. In fact there is no difference conceptually between foreach and foldl.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to roll your own, this appear to work as required:

```
foreach_index(F, [H|T]) ->
    foreach_index(F, [H|T], 0).

foreach_index(F, [H|T], N) ->
    F(H, N),
    foreach_index(F, T, N + 1);

foreach_index(F, [], N) when is_function(F, 2) -> ok.
```

The function `F` will be called with two parameters - the individual entry from the list and its index.