# write for-loop in Erlang

Tags: erlang

How shall I write the method in Erlang

```
for_loop_with_index_and_value(F, L)
```

which is the analog of loop in Go

```
for index, value := range array {
    F(index, value)
}
```

I have read [foreach loop with counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777152/foreach-loop-with-counter)
but I can't rewrite

```
lists:foldl(fun(E,Cnt) -> ..., Cnt+1 end, 0, Y)
```

so that F not return next index.

Ok, thank you all very much. Why

```
for_loop_with_index_and_value(fun(I, V) -> calc(I, V) end, L)
```

work but

```
for_loop_with_index_and_value(fun calc/2, L)
```

doesn't work?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4777367/149530) seems to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Why you can't use `lists:foldl(fun(E,Cnt) -> ..., Cnt+1 end, 0, Y).`? Yes, you can:

```
for_loop_with_index_and_value(F, L) when is_function(F, 2), is_list(L) ->
  lists:foldl(fun(E, I) -> F(I, E), I+1 end, 0, L).
```

More generally `foldl` with index:

```
foldli(F, L, Acc0) when is_function(F, 3), is_list(L) ->
  {_, Result} = lists:foldl(fun(E, {I, Acc}) -> {I+1, F(I, E, Acc)} end, {0, Acc0}, L),
  Result.
```

`map` with index:

```
mapi(F, L) when is_function(F, 2), is_list(L) ->
  {Result, _} = lists:mapfoldl(fun(E, I) -> {F(I, E), I+1} end, 0, L),
  Result.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a recursive function as below.

```
* I: index
* N: max_value
* D: increment

-export([start/0]). 

for(I, N, _) when I == N -> 1; 

    for(I, N, D) when I < N -> 
        io:fwrite("~w~n", [I]), //function body do what ever you want!!!
        for(I+D, N, D).
start() ->
for(0, 4, 2).
```

3rd param `"_"` in `for(I, N, _)` means D is not important so any value can be used as a 3rd param.